# VS 2017 C1083 Cannot open include file:'pcl/io/openni2_grabber.h'

Tags: error-handling, visual-studio-2017, point-cloud-library

I am building a project using PCL.

Here is the code:

```
#include<pcl/io/openni2_grabber.h>

#include<pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
```

My include directories include the following one.

```
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.1\include\pcl-1.8
```

Include Directories screenshot:

[image: the screenshot]

And the file location of openni2_grabber.h is as follow.

```
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.1\include\pcl-1.8\pcl\io
```

But VS2017 shows as follow:

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'pcl/io/openni2_grabber.h': No such 
file or directory
```

I search online and already changed the Windows SDK version into 10.0.16299.0
But the error still exists. Also tried change

```
#include<pcl/io/openni2_grabber.h>
```

into

```
#include"pcl/io/openni2_grabber.h"
```

Not work as well

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem solved. Just pay attention to select "debug" or "release". Keep this selection same and done.

Sorry to bother everyone!